# How to store over 300 words with definitions in a Android studio

Tags: java, android, performance, arraylist, storage

I'm trying to create an android app where you can learn hard words its over 300 words. I'm wondering how I should store the data in java.

I have a text file where all the words are. I have split the text so I have one array with the words and another Array with the definitions, they have the same index. In an activity, I want to make it as clean as possible, because sometimes I need to delete an index and It's not efficient to that with an ArrayList since they all need to move down.
PS. I really don't wanna use a database like Firebase.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `have a text file where all the words are. ` Ok. And where are the definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two different arrays and trying to ensure that their order/indices are matched, you should consider defining your own class.

```
class Word {

     String wordName;
     String wordDefinition;

}
```

You can then make a collection of this using ArrayList or similar.

```
ArrayList<Word> wordList;
```

I know you were concerned about using an ArrayList due to the large number of words, however I think for your use case the ArrayList is fine. Using a database is probably overkill, unless if you want to put in the whole dictionary ;)

In any case, it is better to define your own class and use this as a "wildcard" to collection types which accept these. This link may give you some ideas of other feasible data types.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use a **HashMap**.

The reason for this is because you can set the **key** to be the word and the **value** to be the definition of the word. And then you can grab the definition of the word by doing something like

```
// Returns the definition of word or null if the word isn't in the hashmap   
hashMapOfWords.getOrDefault(word, null);
```

Check out this link for more details on a **HashMap**
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap